# Configuring SSRS 2017 to use LDAP for user authentication

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have an SSRS environment currently configured to use active directory to authenticate users but now have a requirement to use LDAP for authentication.

I have never worked on this kind of configuration and my google searches are not returning any helpful resources about this topic.

Does any one know of a good resource that can get me started on this? 
Has any one ever implemented this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I have on 2016 but not 2017. I doubt this is much of a difference between the two though. For the basics, [read up here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-2017) (hasn't been updated since 2016 so its probably still applicable to SSRS 2017). If you are struggling with the double hop issue then [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253751/ssrs-2016-native-double-hop-windows-authentication).

Comment: Maybe my question is not very clear but Isn't this the opposite of what i want to do?, because like i mentioned, SSRS is already configured for AD authentication but would now like to switch it to an internal enterprise identity management system that uses LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

just in case you did not find anything in the meantime and to add some information for others:

You can find a relatively complete example to implementing custom security here: [GitHub  - CustomerSecuritySample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample)

This example utilizes a SQL database to store users, but you can change the relevant parts to use an LDAP for authentication. We omitted the implementation of the user registration, as all users already exist. There is a SOAP API for SSRS described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/accessing-the-soap-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) that allows you to add users.
Very important: you have to enter an admin user inside the rsreportserver.config:

```
<Security>
        <Extension Name="Forms" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.Authorization, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity">
            <Configuration>
                <AdminConfiguration>
                    <UserName>Your username goes here</UserName>
                </AdminConfiguration>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
    </Security>
```

SSRS can only utilize one authentication method, so your Windows account won't do.