# SSRS - Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' - As user viewing the report

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server, ssrs-2017

I'm trying to set a report in Report Server (SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services 14.0.600.1669) that use the Windows credentials of the user who is viewing the report to query the datasource (SQL Server 2017 14.0.3430.2).

The report is deployed and works correctly if I choose to specify static WAuth credentials in the datasource (Test connection success):

[image]

If I choose to ask the user for Windows credentials it works fine too:

[image]

**BUT** when I choose to access the data source as the user viewing the report (ME, with the same WAuth) I'm reciving the error:

`Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.`

So it seems to not be using my user but another service account.
I've tried both with Microsoft Edge (IE 11 Compatibility Mode) and Chrome with the same result.

I'm not the person who have installed/configured this Report Server.

Can someone help me to find out what could be the problem/suggest what to check?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if the user account used for the SSRS service account has access to the SQL Server instance you are querying from?

Comment: I don't know, bit I'll check. Why? It is necessary?

Comment: I wonder if this could be a double-hop authentication issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems it really was a double-hop authentication issue wich i managed to resolve with the help of IT. I don't know a lot about AD or Kerberos but [this guide](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2010/08/23/reporting-services-double-hop-authentication.aspx) has been pretty helpful for me and IT to catch and resolve the missing configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome version 86, for Chromium Edge and Chrome, you need to add a registry key to enable Kerberos for the browser (to enable double-hop).

The full steps/checklist to enable pass thru authentication for SSRS:

1. run SSRS service as the built-in virtual account. If you run it as a domain service account, you need to make sure a SPN is created for the service (HTTP/your_SSRS_server_name).
2. change Delegation property of the SSRS server machine to "Trust this computer to any service (Kerberos only)". or you can specify the SSRS service to delegate.
3. add RSWindowsNegotiate to your SSRS report config file
4. verify your SSRS web.config's authentication mode is Windows and identity impersonate is true
5. make sure end user's property "Account is sensitive and cannot be delegated" is not checked, and has proper access to the report and all related SQL databases.
6. **Now the key is: add two registry keys on end user's machine:

   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist

   the value of this key should be the SSRS server name. 
   Note this has to be on the end user's machine, not on the SSRS server machine.**